# why the contents of the array in c++ sometimes is not initialized?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, vector, initialization

I am reading the book of effective c++, one some pages it says that:

if you're in the C part of C++ and initialization would probably incur a runtime cost, it's not guaranteed to take place. If you cross into the non-C parts of C++, things sometimes change. This explains why an array (from the C part of C++) isn't necessarily guaranteed to have its contents initialized, but a vector (from the STL part of C++) is.

I wondered why the array which is from c part of c++ is not guaranteed to be initialized, but a vector is? Is not the array from c part is build-in type? but why the vector(from the STL part of C++) guaranteed to be initialized?

Comment: There is no "C part of C++", it's all C++.

Comment: I think it means that `char v[10]` is not initialized, but `std::vector<char>(10, c)` is initialized with value `c` (if you don't provide it, a default value is used).

Comment: As for initialization, local variables aren't initialized unless they have a constructor doing it implicitly. That's why a local array is not initialized, but a `std::vector` is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what is meant in this book with the "C part" is the part of C++ that is inherited from C when C++ was defined. They tried to be very compatible - and that's why I think it legit to call this part of C++ the "C part". Other parts are the STL and the C++ core around classes and such.

Comment: @TobiasLangner [STL is not the C++ standard library](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlIsNotTheCppStandardLibrary). And the inherited parts from C is still C++, they just happen to look the same (but in some cases not *work* the same).

Answer (score 5):

Because that's what the standard says.  Very early in the
specification of C++, it was decided *not* to change the way
types defined in C worked.  So an array (`T[]`) is only
initialized if 1) the type `T` has a constructor, 2) there is an
explicit initialization or 3) it has static lifetime.  Since
`std::vector` isn't inherited from C, there's no C precedent to
be concerned with.  And since some of the operations you can do
on a vector require copying, it has to be initialized.  Copying
an uninitialized value is undefined behavior.

Note that in C++11, `std::array` follows the C rules.  (This is done to allow aggregate initialization.)

Answer (score 1):

When you define `int a[10];` (non-statically), then the contents of `a` are *not initialized*. That's just how C and C++ are designed. You didn't ask for it, you don't get it. (If you wanted an initialized array, you would have said `int a[10]();`.)

In C++, the class `std::vector<int>` is designed to always have well-defined semantics, no matter what you do. So when you define `std::vector<int> v(10)`, you get ten *value-initialized* (i.e. zeroed) elements (similar to the second example above).

However, don't-pay-for-what-you-don't-need applies regardless, and the latter is probably poor C++. What you'd normally use is `reserve`, which, like in C, creates memory but no objects, and objects are created *when needed* and require no further allocation:

```
std::vector<int> v;            // no allocation (hopefully)
v.reserve(10);                 // one single allocation

for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);            // no allocations, guaranteed
```

In a nutshell: C only knows about *memory*. C++ separates the notion of *storage* and *objects*. This finer-grained model goes along with a richer interface. In C, you simply cannot express the concept of "I may need this storage, but I don't have anything to put into it yet."

Comment: Re not paying for what you don't use: using `reserve` and `push_back` is typically more expensive than constructing the vector with the correct size, and simply assigning (at least for built-in types); i.e. `std::vector<int> v( 10 ); for ( int i = 0; i != 10; ++ i ) v[i] = i;` will usually be faster than your code.

Comment: Also, of course, `int a[10];` will be zero initialized if its lifetime is static.

Comment: @JamesKanze: A sensible implementation should make the default constructor of `vector` constexpr and non-allocating, shouldn't it? As a mattor of qoi. It's a question of scale and, too.

Comment: I don't know about `constexpr`; I don't think the standard allows it, and I don't know that it would buy you anything.  On the other hand, although not required by the standard, I would expect the default constructor not to allocate anything.

Answer (score 0):

C++ types like `vector` are actually classes, and they've got a built-in constructor - a procedure which is automatically called when we are creating a variable of this type, and constructors for STL containers can initialize the variable. And when you are using things which come from C, it is much more simple: all you do when you create a variable is just, broadly speaking, taking some part of memory for your own needs. If there is something in this memory, it will stay there just because creating variable of this type (like a simple array) includes only finding memory for it.

Answer (score -1):

the difference is a C-style array is a language primitive, pretty much like an int or a float, so the rule for those is basically do nothing upon declaration.

```
int i;
```

here, i will take any value that was at this position in memory before.

But vector (and other STL containers) are objects, and objects have a constructors, that usually do some work.

```
std::vector<int> v1(10); //create a vector of 10 ints, not initialized, just like int[10] would do
std::vector<int> v2(10, 0);//create a vector of 10 ints, all initialized to zero.
```

Comment: Objects don't always have constructors (e.g. `std::array`).  And `std::vector<int> v1(10);` is exactly identical as `std::vector<int> v2(10, 0);`.  There is _never_ an uninitialized element in a vector.

Comment: `v1` will always have members initialized to default value (0 for `int`). If it was some class instead of `int` members would be initialized using default constructor. The code for `v1` would not compile if member's class has no default constructors (but code for `v2` would, provided that class has a constructor with `int` parameter);